# Laravel $request->all() is empty

Tags: laravel

I start study laravel.
The route to contacts page

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/contacts', [ 'uses' => 'Admin\ContactController@show', 'as' => 'contacts' ] );
```

```
class ContactController extends Controller {
    public function show( Request $request ) {
        print_r( $request->all() );
        return view( 'default.contacts', [ 'title' => 'Contacts' ] );
    }
}
```

Form

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('contacts') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

When i submit the form, i get an array with token.

```
Array
(
    [_token] => JMTxTwh5Cb4sPeDjGcVetgTt2yGy6mDsFs6jW3Tx
)
```

What can be a problem?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Your input fields don't have a `name` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the name in your inputs. Please add to them.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('contacts') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i am stupid, and dont saw the missing name attribute, that solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I just got a form from bootstrap site, and there are not name attribute. http://i.imgur.com/09GHJal.png

Comment: @serii That might be because they submit the form via AJAX.